# What fraction of the standard deviation should the error bars be?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am certainly new to statistics. I did some simulations and got a lot of data. From the data I ran a AWK script to calculate the average $\bar x$; minimum, $x_0$ and standard deviation, $\sigma$ (the one where you divide by $N$, not $N-1$).

Now I want to plot the data. I guess, I can draw the histogram $\bar x$ high but I am confused how long my error bar should be, like should it be,

- one standard deviation long (68% confidence)
- or $2\sigma$ (95% confidence) or $3\sigma$ (99.7% confidence) long.
- or should I draw it from min-value to max-value

Comment: I have see one, two and three standard errors (standard deviation of $\bar X$) used. Two seems most logical to me, but with so many conventions in use, I am almost surely in the minority. I suggest you look to see what the most common practice in your field is. // If this is a paper for publication, save whatever programs you use to make the figures. Whatever choice you make, there is a chance referees or editors will want you to change it. // A different kind of idea is to use boxplots at each point; that will show skewness, if any.

Comment: I think your title would be clearer with the word “multiple” rather than the word “fraction”, because as you say the only sensible  options are $1 \sigma,2 \sigma$ or $3\sigma$

Answer (score 1):

Error bars often represent one standard deviation of uncertainty, one standard error, or a particular confidence interval (e.g., a 95% interval). -Wikipedia

When you are talking about plotting standard deviation, are you sure that the data being plotted is not skewed? If it is, be careful enough to calculate true standard deviations before plotting them.

Comment: How to tell if my data is skewed?

Comment: You need to know what actually you are measuring. If your measured quantity is inherently squared (you are calculated the RMS of the quantity) then you are certain that your error will be skewed. Generally, you calculate the moments of your measured data. The higher moments tend to follow certain characteristics for standard normal distribution. In conclusion you need to know what you are measuring, how you are measuring and how the community in your specific field tackle such problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consistent with the other comments, there is no universally agreed practice across all fields and disciplines.
Thus,  the length of your error bars should be:

- the standard as typically used in your industry / field;
- what you believe your audience ( or reviewers for journal publications!) most likely expect; and
- whatever  you explicitly describe in the caption of your chart.

This last point means that the best way to avoid misinterpretation is to explicitly say in your chart what the length of the error bars represent!